# I want to use C # to get the size of the opaque area of the image

Tags: c#, image, size, opacity

I want to use C# to get the size of the opaque area of the image.But I don't know what to do. Please give some advice to a friend. Thank you.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - You gotta try *something*, even if it doesn't work.. SO isn't a code writing service, and isn't meant to just give advice. It's strictly Q&A.

Comment: You can analyse the pixels of a bitmap: Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x,y); and look at c.A (alpha)

Comment: It would be worthwhile to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you ask a good question, you're definitely more likely to get some good answers. Or any answers.

Comment: Some things we need to know: what type of image, what do you mean by size, what do you mean by opaque?

Answer (score 0):

Because the picture in the game project requires language translation, the fond size of translated text may be too small to be seen clearly or not beautiful. So I want to write a tool to display the fond size data of translated text and source text. The main purpose is to provide reference for my company artists.I found the right way:

```
        private unsafe Region GetRegion(Bitmap bckImage)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        int w = bckImage.Width;
        int h = bckImage.Height;
        BitmapData bckdata = null;
        try
        {
            bckdata = bckImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            uint* bckInt = (uint*)bckdata.Scan0;
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
                {
                    if ((*bckInt & 0xff000000) != 0)
                    {
                        path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(i, j, 1, 1));
                    }
                    bckInt++;
                }
            }
            bckImage.UnlockBits(bckdata); bckdata = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (bckdata != null)
            {
                bckImage.UnlockBits(bckdata);
                bckdata = null;
            }
        }
        Region region = new System.Drawing.Region(path);
        RectangleF[] rects = region.GetRegionScans(new Matrix());
        RectangleF c = RectangleF.Empty;
        for (Int32 i = 1; i < rects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                c = RectangleF.Union(rects[i - 1], rects[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                c = RectangleF.Union( c , rects[i]);
            }
        }
        path.Dispose();
        path = null;
        return region;
    }
```

The variable c is the result I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpsWB.png)

The real parameters are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9DDt.png)
Thank you, too. I hope to be helpful to those who have doubts.